renderedCallback method not getting fired when subscribling to message service in connectedCallback
I have an LWC component that I am using to display hierarchy trees with an external library. I have a message service, and when I subscribe to it in the connectedCallback method, my renderedCallback method is not being executed.
However, when I comment out the subscription, the renderedCallback method gets executed. I’m not sure if the way I am subscribing is incorrect.
    connectedCallback(){
            console.log('>>> inside callback hierarchy... ');
// Uncommenting below line will not execute renderedcallback
            //this.subscribeToMessageChannel();
        }
    
        renderedCallback() {
            console.log('>>> inside rendered callback hierarchy... ');
            if (this.initialized) return;
            this.initialized = true;
    
            Promise.all([
                   loadScript(this, jquery),
                   loadStyle(this, treeflex)
                ])
                    .then(response=> {
                        this.intializeData();
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        this.error = error;
                    });
        }

JS:
    import { createMessageContext, releaseMessageContext, subscribe, unsubscribe } from 'lightning/messageService';
    import CORPORATEGROUPTABLEREFRESH from '@salesforce/messageChannel/corporateGroupTableRefreshChannel__c';

    export default class TreeHierarchy extends LightningElement {
        subscribeToMessageChannel() {
                console.log('>>> Inside subscribeToMessageChannel group hierarchy... ');
                if (!this.subscription) {
                    this.subscription = subscribe(this.context, CORPORATEGROUPTABLEREFRESH, (message) => {
                        this.handleMessage(message);
                    });
                }
            }
        
            handleMessage(message) {
                // Handle the message received
                this.receivedMessage = message.messageText;
                console.log('>>> receivedMessage in group hierarchy... '+this.receivedMessage);
            }
        
            disconnectedCallback() {
                unsubscribe(this.subscription);
                releaseMessageContext(this.context);
            }
}


Make sure the message context is initialized before subscribing and You can try to wrap the subscription in a Promise to ensure it completes before the rendering.
